# Does python manage.py runserver use paster as the server?

Tags: python, django

A little confused, does python manage.py runserver use the paster web server or is this a django specific server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a custom WSGI server built on [`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html) and adapted from wsgiref.